# How do I disable the NDK build in Android Studio 1.0.1

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build an Android Java app using Android Studio 1.0.1. However, my app uses some C++ code that I build using the NDK as controlled by Android.mk and Application.mk files. But Android Studio tries its own build and gets it wrong as it is not using my *.mk files. I know there have been some answers how to do this for previous versions of Android Studio but they evidently do not work for 1.0.1.

So how do I disable Android NDK builds **in Android Studio 1.0.1**?

Comment: It seems the changes need now to be added to the project-specific build.gradle file and not the global build.gradle file.

Comment: comprehensive guide on NDK in AS .... http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the `sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []` to 'android' section of your build.gradle. This will disable automatic call of ndk-build with auto-generated Android.mk.

And yes, this line should be added to the project-specific gradle file.